# Are there any module that works like django admin in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, event-driven

I am search an admin panel like django’s, why nodejs not have one? could you giveme links o a feedback of the benficts that use this kinds of admins. Is necesary by nodejs??

Answer (score 12):

[Express Admin](https://github.com/simov/express-admin) is very similar to how the Django admin looks.

It's really a light weight solution and it's definitely not a framework but at least you can easily create an admin panel for your database.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking into this again today and came across [Strapi](https://github.com/strapi/strapi) which looks quite promising. I'm going to play around with it, and am also looking forward to their 3.0 release which is planned for this year.

It's a shame there isn't a more solid solution. I constantly find myself wishing I was building a Django application because the admin panel makes development and administration so much easier. The problem is that with all frameworks, Django is not a good solution for some applications. With that, the search continues for a flexible, robust admin panel for Node. Perhaps Strapi is what I've been waiting for.

Comment: 3.0 is in alpha now but not stable yet :(

Comment: Did you find it? I'm looking for one too

Answer (score 7):

There is a thing called admin-bro (right now in beta). https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/admin-bro

It supports mongoose and sequelizejs ORMs

example app here: https://admin-bro-example-app.herokuapp.com/admin

- login: test@example.com
- password: password

Answer (score 6):

[Keystone JS](http://keystonejs.com/) is a framework that creates an admin UI. So you can manage there the content and users. It is built on Express. Maybe it is what you need...

Answer (score 0):

https://getsubzero.today is probably close to what you are looking for.

All it needs is the database and it autogenerates the api and the ui (both of which you can fully customize with TS/React)